# Possible to download these webpages as a book?

Tags: wget

I would like to download a SQL tutorial here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp, as a book with all linked SQL related sections.

Here is my command

```
wget -r -np -nH  -p -k  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp
```

Under the downloaded `sql` directory, I get some asp files, which I don't know how to open in Chrome.

Did I download the webpages correctly? How shall I do? Thanks!

Comment: Why would anyone download w3schools books?

Comment: Why not? Do you have recommendations for learning SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use an appropriate tool such as `httrack` and not waste my time in trying to coax this out of a tool such as `wget` or `curl`. Here's how you can download the URL that you're asking about, I did it myself and it even works just fine in Chrome!

```
$ httrack http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp
Mirror launched on Sat, 13 Sep 2014 22:50:32 by HTTrack Website Copier/3.48-19 [XR&CO'2014]
mirroring http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp with the wizard help..
Done.57: www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql_view.asp?x= (0 bytes) - OK
Thanks for using HTTrack!
```

After it's complete I'm left with the following directory structure:

```
$ ls -l
total 36
-rw-r--r--. 1 slm slm 4243 Sep 13 22:50 backblue.gif
-rw-rw-r--. 1 slm slm  181 Sep 13 22:51 cookies.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 slm slm  828 Sep 13 22:50 fade.gif
drwx------. 2 slm slm 4096 Sep 13 22:51 hts-cache
-rw-rw-r--. 1 slm slm  736 Sep 13 22:51 hts-log.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 slm slm 5057 Sep 13 22:50 index.html
drwxr-xr-x. 3 slm slm 4096 Sep 13 22:50 www.w3schools.com
```

To check things out simply navigate to the `index.html` file at the root level and you'll be greeted with the following page:

[image: ss1]

Clicking the link will take you to your downloaded pages:

[image: ss2]

And just for measure, here I'm clicking one of the side links to demonstrate that it can navigate just fine.

[image: ss3]

#### References

- [httrack website](http://www.httrack.com/)
- [httrack documentation](http://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html)

Comment: Do you know how to convert the downloaded html files into a pdf file?

Answer (score 1):

First you should copy your current working directory to a test directory for dry-run and try this below.

You should then run:

this should convert file to an html response from an asp page (getting    webserver response with -O command and put the page to a filename.html file after fetching)

```
  wget -O filename.html http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp
```

then replace the extension names from the pages

```
  for f in *.old_file_extention; do mv $f `basename $f to .new_file_extension; done;
```

then replace file linkings to .html from .asp linkings from pages in all .html pages

```
  sed -i 's/.asp/.html/' *.html
```

try that; then you should be able to open up your webpages with links
 working correctly. you may need to work something out with the first command because it only gets one page at a time. You have to combine what you have.

Comment: Chome reads .html output

Comment: When I tried: sudo wget -r http://www.w3schools.com/sql, it downloaded entire website to /www.w3schools.com folder, you can try to convert all .asp to .html files with the commands above

Comment: httrack sounds like a good soulution. what I have is a way to do it if there wasn't any httrack

Answer (score 0):

Try to :

```
wget -r http://www.w3schools.com/sql
```

Yes i got result

I have the following dirs and files:

```
mohsen@debian:~/offline docs/www.w3schools.com$ ls
about  angular  aspnet  bootstrap  css  default.asp  favicon.ico  forum  html  index.html  jquery  js  php  robots.txt  sitemap  sql  stdtheme.css  xml
```

Comment: do you get asp files?

Comment: i got a set of *.asp as html format, Why do you need asp?

Comment: some of asp file are downloaded : `mohsen@debian:~/offline docs/www.w3schools.com$ ls sql/
default.asp  sql_and_or.asp  sql_distinct.asp  sql_insert.asp  sql_intro.asp  sql_orderby.asp  sql_select.asp  sql_syntax.asp  sql_update.asp  sql_where.asp`

Comment: You have to use them as html file.

Comment: How to use asp as html?

Comment: use default page and use its link.

Comment: WHen open an asp file with Chrome, it ask me to save the asp file again. I don't know how to render it.

Answer (score -2):

This may be an short answer and hopefully it'll help. I would wget the .asp file and then rename it to an file with a .html extension. This will take the .asp html output and open the file as .html in a browser.