# After downloading an .asp or .php file, can it be converted to a .html file?

Tags: wget, download, web

I wonder if downloading files via `wget` and having them named `.asp` or `.php`  means that I download the webpage? Aren't these executable files?

If so, after downloading an `.asp` or `.php` file, can it be converted to an `.html` file?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with Unix & Linux.

Comment: Which site does it have something to do with?

Comment: @Tim: PHP files like ASP files, JSP, as well as shell scripts and perl scripts (and ruby and python and a host of others) are programs. You don't "convert" them to HTML. You execute them, and if that program generated HTML, you get HTML out. To be able to execute them though, you need to right environment & dependencies.

Comment: @Mat: "To be able to execute them though, you need to right environment & dependencies." Do you mean I have no hope since no one except the web author knows those "right environment & dependencies"?

Comment: @Tim: there's always hope, you can derive some of the dependencies of the code by looking at it (you need to know/learn PHP or whatever). But in general, there's calls to a database somewhere in there, or some other private API, or references to private headers, etc... so it's not going to work.

Comment: I'm a bit curious about why you ask this question though. Did you download something from the web and got a file called ".php"? If that's the case, that file probably isn't PHP but rendered HTML (unless that webserver was seriously misconfigured).

Comment: @Mat Yes, some webpages I tried to download in Firefox were php files. What about ASP files, any hope?

Comment: @Tim: they are probably not PHP files, did you check? (For ASP, same deal exactly, except I don't know if interpreters for ASP exist other than on Windows - so even less hope)

Comment: @Tim Maybe it is good to read on "server side" versus "client side". ASP, PHP are serverside, that is, processed on the server. HTML/CSS are client side, processed by your web browser normally. Compare with a source code that I compile (server side), then I give the executable to you, which you can execute (client side).

Comment: Even though the files are named `.asp` they're actually HTML files. Look at their content to confirm this, but the use of the extension `.asp` is b/c that's the technology that was used to implement that particular site. That's the name that the browser uses when it downloads the files, and hence the name that's used when the files are written to disk, but they're still HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the files are named `.asp` they're actually HTML files. Look at their content to confirm this, but the use of the extension `.asp` is because that's the technology that was used to implement that particular site. That's the name that the browser uses when it downloads the files, and hence the name that's used when the files are written to disk, but they're still HTML.

You can also confirm the file's type using the `file` command:

```
$ file some.asp
```

In your earlier question where you posited how does one download a bunch of pages from the w3school website ([Possible to download these webpages as a book?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155423/possible-to-download-these-webpages-as-a-book)). You showed this command:

```
$ wget -r -np -nH  -p -k  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp
```

Notice the results of the files that that command produced for you when you ran it:

```
$ file ./sql/sql_func_count.asp
./sql/sql_func_count.asp: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

#### So this is a bug with `wget` then, right?

No! This is not a bug, it's just how `wget` and `curl` behave. This is part of why I directed you to use `httrack` in your other Q&A linked above. If you notice the results that it produces, the names of the files are all `.html` with `httrack`. `wget` and `curl` are respecting the names of the files within the URL as they are the names of the actual files that you downloaded when you accessed them. URLs do not really have any concept of extensions, that's a OS-ism. URLs are just that, Universal Resource Locators.

URLs are meant for uniquely finding content on the internet, not for storing it locally, for later consumption. When you want to download online content for this type of use, you want to use a tool that can actually mirror that content locally and make it locally navigatable.

Tools such as `httrack` are essentially violating the consistency of the URLs for the sake of allowing this locally stored content to be navigatable, offline. `wget` and `curl` can be coaxed to do this, but it's typically much more cumbersome and error-prone, and so as a general rule, discouraged.

It's best to use the proper tool for the job. For mirroring online content locally, `httrack` is the appropriate tool!

Comment: That's right. Is that considered a bug for wget and browsers?

Comment: See A for updates.

Comment: yes. wget download the same webpages with .asp as their extension names. But httrack will change the ext to .http. So why isn't that a bug of wget?

Comment: See the rest of my comment, I wasn't finished typing it. I've moved that comment into the A.

Comment: @Tim - more updates, LMK if that makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The file extensions you mentioned are script files.  These are files that are executed like programs.  They are executed when you click on them on a webpage to cause the effect that you get when you're browsing the site.